# Macro to Copy/Paste rows into new worksheet depending on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a list of names and data with the following headings:

```
Year    Forename    Surname DOB Gender  UPN
```

The data variable is in that there are 7 years (Year 1-Year 7) in column 1 (A)

I would like to run a macro which

1. Copies the rows into its own worksheet depending on what year the child is in on column A.
2. If possible it should create a new worksheet e.g. Year 1, Year 2, Year 3 etc. with the relevant data in with all 6 columns of data.

I have tried for a few days to mix and match up several macros to no avail and I don't want to use ifs/lookups as it will be for the admin staff and want it at the click of a button.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Dean.  Unfortunately SU is not a macro-writing service, but we can/will help with specific problems you run into while writing your macro.  Please edit your question and include what you've got so far, point out where you're getting stuck, include what you've tried already in attempts to resolve it, and what the results of those attempts were.

Comment: Ok thanks will for the heads up I will get back to you once I have tried a few more times.

Comment: I suggest recording a macro while performing these manual steps: =sort by Year column -> AutoFilter by first year -> create a new sheet and rename it to first year -> copy visible range (all rows) -> in the new sheet select first cell, right-click and Paste-Special - Values. Stop recording

Comment: Many thanks - I have tried this and managed to record and use my first macro...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
Sub yearAssign()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo SheetError
    sheetname = "initial"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = Sheets(sheetname)
    totalsheets = wkb.Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To totalsheets
        Set wks1 = wkb.Worksheets(i)
        thename = wks1.Name
        If thename <> sheetname Then
            wks1.Rows.Clear
        End If
    Next i
    totalrows = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To totalrows
        theyear = wks.Cells(i, 1)
        Set wks1 = Sheets(theyear)
            lastrow = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If lastrow = 2 Then
                wks.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A1")
            End If
            wks.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A" & lastrow)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    finish = MsgBox("Finished", vbInformation)

SheetError:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = theyear
        Resume
    End If
End Sub
```

Go to VBA /Macro, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code on the right side of the window.

It assumes that the data is in a sheet called *initial"*, change the line `sheetname="initial"`to the name you are using.