# Macro to Copy/Paste specific columns of a row into new worksheet depending on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

This is my first post so please bear with me.

I am using a code ([from this site](https://superuser.com/questions/984513/macro-to-copy-paste-rows-into-new-worksheet-depending-on-criteria)) that looks at a list in the A column of a specific worksheet and creates/names new worksheets from this list (if they don't already exist).  It also copies the data from the rows with the matching names into their respective sheets.

What I am wondering is how to alter the code so that instead of copying the entire row to the new sheet, it only copies columns `A:P`. I would really appreciate any help.  Here is the code:

```
Sub yearAssign()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo SheetError
    sheetname = "initial"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = Sheets(sheetname)
    totalsheets = wkb.Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To totalsheets
        Set wks1 = wkb.Worksheets(i)
        thename = wks1.Name
        If thename <> sheetname Then
            wks1.Rows.Clear
        End If
    Next i
    totalrows = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To totalrows
        theyear = wks.Cells(i, 1)
        Set wks1 = Sheets(theyear)
        lastrow = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If lastrow = 2 Then
            wks.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A1")
        End If
        wks.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A" & lastrow)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    finish = MsgBox("Finished", vbInformation)

    SheetError:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = theyear
        Resume
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest that you record a macro of your own. It's super easy, press record, do your procedure, press stop, examine code. Using this code will only frustrate you and it's for a particular problem; that's how VBa works -- ti's problem specific. Algorithms are reusable, but coding for a job is not.

Answer (score 0):

The lines that are doing the actual copying of entire rows are these:

```
wks.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A1")

wks.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A" & lastrow)
```

So, modifying them as follows will cause them to copy only columns `A:P`:

```
wks.Range("A1:P1").Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A1")

wks.Range("A" & i & ":" & "P" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(theyear).Range("A" & lastrow)
```

Also, the code has several other issues, including but not necessarily limited to the following:

1) Many variable declarations are missing:

```
Dim sheetname As String
Dim totalsheets As String
Dim theyear As String
Dim thename As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim finish As Integer
Dim totalrows As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
```

2) `sheetname` is being set before variables are declared

3) There should be a generic error handler, and `Application.ScreenUpdating` should be set to `True`  when any error occurs (otherwise, `Application.ScreenUpdating` will remain `False` when the procedure completes after an error)

4) The occurrences of `Sheets(theyear)` in the lines doing the copying should be replaced with `wks1`, because the `wks1` variable has already been set to `Sheets(theyear)`

Please note that specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of the Module will help call attention to issues such as #1 and #2, as then the code will not compile until the issues are addressed.